# Center a picture on top of another picture using position absolute

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put two different things on top of an image inside a media object from bootstrap. One of them is a badge/label which should be placed on the bottom right corner of the image, but currently I can only get it to appear on the top left. The other is a play icon, which should appear smack bang in the middle of the image.

Here is the code, and also a jsfiddle:

HTML:

```
      <a class="news-link" href="#">
        <div class="media">
          <div class="image-container">
            <img class="pull-left img-responsive" src="http://i59.tinypic.com/16m9f1f.png">
            <div class="video-badge">
              <h6>Badge</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="play-icon">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i57.tinypic.com/20jptok.png">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading">Title</h4>
            Content
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
```

CSS (as well as some others and Bootstrap which I put on the jsfiddle):

```
.image-container {
    position: relative;
}

.image-container img {
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.video-badge {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 25px 5px 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.video-badge h6 {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fafafa;
    margin: 0;
}

.video-badge:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background: #5e4c33;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-25deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-25deg);
  transform: skew(-25deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.play-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 25px 5px 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 85px;
}
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/pgo7h903/

Answer (score 1):

Change your css like this

CSS Code:

```
        .image-container {
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
        }
   .play-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 85px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 75px 25px 5px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.video-badge {
    bottom: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px 25px 5px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
    .media img.pull-left.img-responsive {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
```

see demo http://jsfiddle.net/JentiDabhi/65ajj56j/4/

Comment: Hey, not sure you understood my meaning correctly. I want the badge to be in the bottom right corner of the image, and I want the play icon in the middle of the image. I'll re-write the original post to clarify a bit.

Comment: Why you are using `display: inline-block;` and `float: left;` simultaneously?

Comment: @JentiDabhi the badge should be in the bottom right corner of the image. As mentioned below, I tried something similar to this with the play icon, but when you resize the window the two objects are not displayed correctly, which isn't ideal

Comment: Do you have any thoughts? I'm still playing with the code

Answer (score 1):

@JentiDabhi 's answer works but isn't an efficient way to code, as it uses up a lot of code. Try this:

```
.play-icon {
    width: auto;
    margin: 65px;
}
```

Add that into your CSS and it should center it. If you feel it's not centered, change the `margin` to `margin-right` and `margin-top` and change it there.

**EDIT**

For the badge, add this:

```
.video-badge {
    margin-left: 201px;
    margin-top: 143px;
}
```

Now it should be at the bottom right of the image.

Comment: Just saw your other comment. Where did you want the badge? I know bottom right, but on top of the main image or next to it?

Comment: The badge should be on the bottom right of the image (the small image on the left of the person), and the play icon should be in the middle of that same image. It's essentially a video preview image so that's what they're for. Sorry I wasn't more clear in my first post.

Comment: It should be inside the image. The problem with this method is that if you resize the window then surely the position will be incorrect? The same with the play icon

Comment: do you have any ideas? I'm still playing with the code